# Disable class certificates information checking (Java)

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I created a library that loads a jar directly into the current classpath to launch one of its class.
But the injected jar contains certificates, so I got this error :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "TestClass" signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

This is normal, but I can't get rid of it. It is normal, because two different jar are "colliding", but, I can't delete the certificate of the JAR because it's a third-party one.

So, can I disable the class cert checking ? Or do something to get rid of that error ?

I think I need to overwrite the `ClassLoader.checkCerts` method... but that's dirty...

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to work with two versions or two implementations of a library at the same time, such as for part of an upgrade process, then you need to work with the ClassLoaders.

When a Class has to be resolved, the standard Java ClassLoaders first ask their parent ClassLoader, the one that loaded them, for the class and only if the parent cannot find it do they attempt to load it themselves. This "parent first" approach provides security (as loaded classes are impossible to override) and stability (as you cannot have two versions of the same class in use at the same time). Many application containers do this differently so that the implementation of the container does not affect the implementation of the application it contains.

To use two versions of a library, say V1 and V2, in the same application you need to use at least two ClassLoaders.

In my opinion the cleanest implementation is to omit all mention of V1 and V2 from your application's standard class path. You then create two ClassLoader instances, one for V1 and its dependencies, and the other for V2 and its dependencies. When either version runs the other is not on the class path and so there is no conflict. Sadly a "clean" implementation is not always possible.

To have most of your application continue to use V1 and a select part of it use V2 then you need to use a class loader that allows you to over-ride the load order so its classes are preferred to those of the parents. I found an implementation of such at https://github.com/kamranzafar/JCL. JCL allows you set the search order for classes and resources and will create proxies automatically for you so that you don't need to use reflection to work with the V2 code.

Note that the JCL documentation doesn't mention that one should invoke the `initialise` method on its `JarClassLoader` class after configuring it and before using it.

There are a couple of things you cannot do with ClassLoaders:

1. If you are trying to replace a signed class with a different version, it would break the spirit of the signing if you could do that, so you cannot. This means you have to create your own unsigned jar.
2. If you are trying to replace a signed class in a cryptographic library, that could create a security loophole so you may find you need to sign the library with your own signing key, or even a signing key certified by Oracle as the JRE is very fussy about who can load cryptographic classes.